# ClearCase: Visual Studio Debugger confused by VOB symbolic link

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, clearcase

I have a C++ Project in Visual Studio, that is managed by Rational ClearCase.

In it there exists the following source code structure:

```
\Dir1\Source.cpp
     \Source.h
\Dir2\Source.cpp --> ..\Dir1\Source.cpp
     \Source.h   --> ..\Dir1\Source.h
```

The two files in `Dir2` are VOB symbolic links, so ClearCase knows they are the same file, but Visual Studio does not.

When debugging the Project Visual Studio jumps to break points in `Dir2` but I can only edit the file in `Dir1`.
When I try to edit the file in `Dir1` ClearCase tries to check out the file (again) and runs into the following message:

```
_______________________________________________________
| Problem Occurred                        | _ | □ | X |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
| 'Checking out artifacts' has encountered a problem. |
| A problem has occurred.                             |
|                               ______ ______________ |
|                               | OK | | Details >> | |
|                               ------ -------------- |
|_____________________________________________________|
```

Unfortunately the `Details` are empty.

I cannot use regular symbolic links, as they are quite useless in Windows and the ClearCase server permits logical links.
In addition I can't move the files from `Dir1`, as they are used by other modules.

Can I somehow force Visual Studio to debug the program using the editable file in `Dir1`?